# Jenkins with Git Hub clone issue

Tags: github, jenkins

I am creating a Jenkins job with clone my project from GitHub.

The Jenkins work-space location is configured as follows.

`${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}/`

In Github, I created a sample project called "java".

Step1. I created a Jenkins job with name "test" and configured my github url.

While building, Jenkins clone the project called "java" in

`~/.jenkins/workspace/test/java`

Now jenkins give the following error while build.

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\pxp167.jenkins\workspace\test). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Could anyone please help me to understand where I need to change my configuration

Comment: 1. Is your Github project `java` a maven project? 2. Please paste a screenshot of your Jenkins job config page to give us more info.

Comment: you should choose a freestyle project unless you specifically want to run it as maven; though if that were the case I would guess this question would not be being asked.

Comment: Thanks all. I have missed pom.xml configuration. Thanks for your support.